# Access denied to download file using libcurl

Tags: c++, qt, curl, libcurl

I am developing an application in qt c++ which download the file from website and process it.

I have used libcurl in qt for downloading the file.

I am downloading the file using link example:
 "http://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2014/OCT/cm01OCT2014bhav.dbf.zip"

When I download this file using browser It gets downloaded. But when I download the file using libcurl, then I get reply in console as `access denied`

I have tried to download some other files like curl libbrary using libcurl form the same program just replacing the url, and it worked fine then.
Example : "http://mirrors.kernel.org/sources.redhat.com/cygwin/x86_64/release/curl/curl-7.37.1-1.tar.xz"

Is there anything need to use in the libcurl like agents or like that?
Or its server functionality to disallow the automated downlaod?

Thank you.

Comment: I get 'Access Denied' error on your first link even in a browser.

Comment: I am using google chrome latest version, and it opened just by clicking the link in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like  (specify user agent and redirect to a file, this is on your linux shell)

```
curl -A "Mozilla/4.0" http://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2014/OCT/cm01OCT2014bhav.dbf.zip >yourfile.dbf.zip
```

Edit: 
Just realized that you are downloading it through your c++ code. 
The above example shows that the server hosting the file has permission based on user-agent. So, in your code, you need to specify a dummy user agent something like "Mozilla/4.0" that should return the buffer of the file.